# Help identifying a voltage regulator

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, raspberry-pi, driver, touchscreen

I'm trying to build a portable screen so that I can watch movies around my apartment if I need to move away from my TV screen (think a WiiU gamepad or a tablet). I have many raw components and I think I will be able to succeed as long as I can solve all of the little problems (classic statement, I know).

My system contains a Raspberry Pi along with a wifi dongle, some button/joystick inputs, and a 7" touch screen. My background is mostly in CS/programming, so I don't know exactly how to deal with powering the system. I have a relatively large battery supply that has two outputs of 5V/2.1 A and 5V/1A so I know I can power the RPi along with the simple components directly connected to it, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to power the screen/driver. I can make the system work if I plug a 12V/1A power supply into the board but with my 5V battery supply that clearly does not work on its own. Attached is a picture of the power regulator.

Is there any way to convert my 5V battery (either the 2.1A or 1A port) to work with this board? I'd be willing to purchase other parts and/or deconstruct the video driver board if needed. (I know Watt-wise I can /almost/ make it, so I'm hopeful that someone out there has a creative solution!)

The markings of the regulator on the board (if you're having trouble reading it):

```
  AA20 C
HY2576 S
-ADJ  P+
```

I can't find anything on Google about the regulator, but my google-fu may just be off.

[image: Picture of the video driver's power regulation]

Comment: That's the HOOYI clone of the [LM2576](http://www.ti.com/product/lm2576), adjustable version.

Comment: I suppose there's a box for answers down there? ;-)

Comment: I've got the same board, and am doing the same thing.  I found this http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2576.pdf which identifies the pin out, but I'm concerned that the top 2 pins of the connector to the right of your picture are labeled as 12v and seem to be connected straight to my LCD screen.  I've had another screen working by simply removing the regulator and connecting my (already regulated usb) 5V straight to the 5v out from the regulator.  Have you tried this yet?

Answer (score 1):

That is a a clone of the LM2576 buck regulator , voltage range for it is 7-40v in general for displays output is 5v.

Comment: Huayi (华羿) datasheet: http://www.hymexa.com/asset/file/file/product/IC/HY2576%20datasheet%20V1.0-OK.pdf